# How to use pre-saved card detail to populate squareup SQpayment form

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, square

I have implemented squareup payment using SQpaymentForm and PHP square SDK in my Ionic application. It's working fine but i want to allow my users to use saved card detail for payment. How to implement this?? Is their any way as i did not found any helpful information over internet.Following are the code i have written

```js
 var data = {
          "amount_money": {
            "amount": base.amount,
            "currency": "USD"
          },
          "card_nonce": nonce,
          "reference_id":base.orderID,
          "note": "some optional note",
          "customer_id":"1234",
          "delay_capture": false
        }

        var orderUrl='http://demo2.xxxxxdemo.com/101094/process-card/process-card.php';
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json','Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        let body = JSON.stringify(data);

        const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({  
            'Content-Type':  'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer sandbox-sq0atb-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',  
          })
        };
        base.Http.post(orderUrl,body).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(function (success) {
        console.log(success)         
        },error=>{
          console.log(error)
        })
      }
```

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for : https://medium.com/square-corner-blog/recurring-charges-with-php-and-card-on-file-60f2bcb9aeac

Answer (score 0):

If you have saved your customer's card details using the Customers API and have a "card on file" for them, you can simply process a transaction using the [`customer_card_id`](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-charge) in the `customer_card_id` key for the body of your Charge request.

Here is an example of the minimum JSON body required for a card on file charge:

```
{
  "idempotency_key": "REPLACE_WITH_IDEMPOTENCY_KEY",
  "amount_money": {
    "amount": 100,
    "currency": "USD"
  },
  "customer_card_id": "REPLACE_WITH_CUSTOMER_CARD_ID",
  "customer_id":"REPLACE_WITH_CUSTOMER_ID"
}
```

Make sure to read the details of the overview on the [Charge endpoint](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v2#endpoint-charge) since they give guidelines on how to ensure you provide sufficient information for still getting [Chargeback Protection](https://squareup.com/help/article/5394).

You need to provide *at least*:

- `buyer_email_address`

and

- At least one of `billing_address` or `shipping_address`